# C++ First character Input being Ignored

Tags: c++, arrays, input, getline

I'm having an issue where I want to input elements of a string array but the first letter is ignored for all the elements except for the first one. For example, i write `pepperoni, olvies, cheese`, it will print out `pepperoni, lives, heese`. If you look at my code, I think it is because of the `cin.ignore()` that comes before inputting `name`.

```
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, name);
        petes.setCustomerName(name);

        for (int i = 0; i < numToppings; i++)
        {
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, toppingNames[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Ok, and your specific reason for calling `ignore()` is what, exactly? Why do you think you need it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the first ```ignore()``` keeps the code from skipping the user inputting their name. the second ```ignore()```  in the loop makes it where it does not become an infinite loop when the user inputs the first  topping

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i figured it out. the second ```ignore()``` needed to be outside the loop before it

Comment: The purpose of `ignore()` is not to "keep the code from skipping the user inputting their name". `ignore()`  "extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and including " a default or a non-default delimiter. To determine whether or not `ignore()` should be used, and when, it is necessary to establis whether, in order for the program to produce correct results it is necessary to extract and discard characters from the input stream.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a cin before your first cin.ignore.

To remember a simple trick, always use cin.ignore right after any **cin >> any_variable** you use in your code.

*cin* stores an "Enter" (i.e. '\n' character) value in the input stream. Because of this character in the input stream, if you use a command like *getline* anywhere after the cin in your code, your getline will be ignored.

For example, in your case, the first *getline(cin, name)* was being ignored because you might have used a cin before.

However, there's an issue in the use of cin.ignore. While it is true that it will help you a lot when used after cin statements, it can also be quite annoying when used incorrectly.

Consider a case where you have not used a cin statement and the first statement in your code is a *getline*. Now, if you use *cin.ignore* before the getline statement, the cin.ignore will wait for a character to be entered, will remove it from the input stream and then the remaining code will be executed.

This is because in such a scenario, there was no *'\n' character* stored in the input stream and hence, input stream was **empty**. Therefore, cin.ignore waited for a character to be entered before proceeding further.

For example, consider this code,

```
int main() 
{
string var; 
cin.ignore(); 
getline(cin, var); 
}
```

Suppose you enter "David" for your "var" input. Now, since at the time of cin.ignore, there was **nothing in input stream**, so cin.ignore waited for a character to come. As soon as you *pressed D, cin.ignore removed the D from the input stream* and then proceeded further. Now, *avid* will be taken into the input stream and as soon as you pressed Enter key ('\n'), getline will store "avid" in your "var" variable, ultimately giving an incorrect reuslt.

Consider the same example but with an cin statement before,

```
int main()
{
int a;
string var;
cin >> a; 
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, var); 
}
```

In this case, when your *cin >> a* statement will execute, it will store the *'\n' character* in the input stream. Now, cin.ignore will notice the '\n' character in the input stream, so it will remove that character and will proceed further. Now, if you enter "David" and then press enter, your complete word "David" will be stored in the "var" because cin.ignore ignored the '\n' character stored by the cin statement and will not interfere with your "David" string.

But, suppose you do the same without cin.ignore() statement,

```
int main()
{
int a;
string var;
cin >> a; 
// cin.ignore();
getline(cin, var); 
}
```

As always, the *cin >> a* statement will store a *'\n' character* in the input stream. Then it will proceed further. There is no cin.ignore in this case however so it will move directly to getline.

getline statement will notice a *'\n'* in the input stream, so it will think that the user has already entered his input and will store whatever's in the input stream in the variable "var". Input stream had nothing in it except the '\n' character so your *var variable will be empty*

This is the reason why you should use cin.ignore() but it should always be used with care.

Moving on to your example, your *name* variable was being ignored because there must have been a "\n" character stored in the input stream and hence, getline was assuming that you have already entered your input. Using cin.ignore was necessarily in this case.

However, after that command, there was no *cin* statement, and hence input stream was empty. But in your for loop, you have again used cin.ignore before taking input by using getline statement. Since the input stream is empty, so cin.ignore will always ignore the first character of whatever input you enter and the remaining input will then be stored in the variable you are using with getline.

Just to be careful and to avoid this error, it is always good to use cin.ignore right after your cin statements rather than using before getline statements. In this way, you will be ignoring the '\n' stored by cin easily and cin.ignore will not interfere with your getline statements either (which might happen if you use it right before getline statements)